# convert sql update with subquery to dql

Tags: php, symfony

Good morning every one . Please i need your help. I'm trying to convert this sql update to dql . here is the sql code

```
UPDATE `crc_voyage_vehicule_declarer` 
SET `vehicule_declarer_id`= (
    select id from crc_vehicule_declarer 
    where immatriculation = "CE360BF"
)
WHERE `vehicule_declarer_id`=(
    select id from crc_vehicule_declarer 
    where immatriculation="CE931GG"
)
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but i think DQL does't support Subselects in that way you need. For this you can use the native query version.

https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Then you can use a normal query.